# PHP Extensions activate in Ununtu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache-kafka, bitnami

Ive installed an extension (rdkafka) to the server (ubuntu)

and added the extension to php.ini

```
extension=rdkafka.so
```

but when i go to phpinfo(), the rdkafka is not activated

when i try this command:

```
phpenmod rdkafka
```

i got this error:

```
WARNING: Module rdkafka ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available
```

on extensions folder,, all the extensions colored green, except rdkafka is white

Answer (score 0):

1. install PHP pecl and pear

   sudo apt install php-pear
2. Add backports repository. Current ext-rdkafka depends on librdkafka version 0.11.0 or greater. So follow [official instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) but use stretch-backports
3. Install librdkafka-dev package from backports:

   sudo apt -t stretch-backports install librdkafka-dev
4. Update apt:

   sudo apt update
5. Install PECL-package:

   sudo pecl install rdkafka
6. Enable PHP-extension in PHP config. Add to php.ini:

   extension=rdkafka.so
7. Restart apache

   sudo apachectl -k restart

Comment: this procedure not works for me on ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04. i cannot find in php.info enabled or using it via php libs dependcies